# What is the status of the make it happen for permissions on activities and cases?

Tags: activities, civicase

The make it happen listed [here](https://civicrm.org/make-it-happen#Improved%20permissions%20for%20activities%20and%20cases) is something we're interested in having. What does it mean to be a "confirmed" make it happen? Is this particular capability coming soon?

(I emailed the make it happen lead and one other address associated with make it happen and haven't heard anything yet) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project has been funded for a "phase 1" MVP targeting 4.7 release in late January, which in brief will:

- Provide an acl hook for cases and option lists
- Not create a UI at this time
- Leave the door open for other entities to be affected by this hook such as activities, but that work will likely be 6 months or so away

Comment: I've found this issue re case ACL: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17645.
Did anything get implemented for activity ACL?

Comment: @davejenx - not yet. Implementing it at the api level would be quite easy. This would also cover reports. However, as was the problem with Cases, most of the core code does not go through the api, so there's a fair amount of cleanup to be done to make the acls get respected by forms & searches.

Comment: Thanks @coleman. Would you be able  to give a ball-park estimate of the work involved in implementing activity ACL, so that it's respected by forms & searches? Is anyone lined up to sponsor this work? Feel free to PM or email me if that seems better.

Comment: I'd suggest you contact JMA Consulting - they are currently doing work in this area. In fact we just merged in this PR of theirs: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9916

Comment: Thanks. I've commented at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20207?focusedCommentId=102200&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-102200 .