# ACL permissions Activities

Tags: activities, acl

I'm trying to make a permission, to limit view some activities types
(A user with a specific role can't view a some activities types)

I was checking the hook permissions but i don't find the way(version civicrm 4.4).

Any idea to focus this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You can install the [Activity Type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There was a proposal for [ACLs for Activities and Cases](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/ACLs+for+Activities+and+Cases) and an [ACL Hook for Cases](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17645) has been implemented but not yet for activities. See [What is the status of the make it happen for permissions on activities and cases?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/what-is-the-status-of-the-make-it-happen-for-permissions-on-activities-and-cases).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question - but I'd suggest upgrading from 4.4 before putting effort into developing something to do that.

Comment: [Aidan](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/225/aidan) Thank you, i will do it in this way